# Handling ports in Azure using Flask Application

Tags: azure, docker, flask, port, web-deployment

I am very new to web development and currently trying to deploy a Flask application on Microsoft Azure. The deployment is successful but the website loads for a very long time and then crashes...
The errors I get in the Application logs are as follows:

```
2020-04-24 11:05:10.813 INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2020-04-24 11:05:14.160 INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container <container name> for site <appname>
2020-04-24 11:05:29.738 INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container <container name>. Elapsed time = 15.5776184 sec
2020-04-24 11:05:46.605 INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container <container name>. Elapsed time = 32.4451731 sec
2020-04-24 11:06:02.843 INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container <container name>. Elapsed time = 48.6833158 sec
2020-04-24 11:06:20.077 INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container <container name>. Elapsed time = 65.9168483 sec
2020-04-24 11:06:35.755 INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container <container name>. Elapsed time = 81.5946978 sec
2020-04-24 11:06:51.273 INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container <container name>. Elapsed time = 97.1126494 sec
2020-04-24 11:07:06.740 INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container <container name>. Elapsed time = 112.5797427 sec
2020-04-24 11:07:22.295 INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup request for container <container name>. Elapsed time = 128.1349342 sec
2020-04-24 11:09:28.785 ERROR - Container <container name> for site <appname> did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 254.6249399 sec
2020-04-24 11:09:28.833 ERROR - Container <container name> didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2020-04-24 11:09:29.008 INFO  - Stoping site <appname> because it failed during startup.
```

What am I missing?

In my main.py file I set app.run(debug=True); so no ports and hosts specified, is this ok?
In the Cloud Shell I set:

```
az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <app-name> --settings WEBSITES_PORT=8000
```

Does anyone know where the problem is?

All the best,
snowe

Answer (score 0):

Hosting your webapp on Azure App Service (Web App) you can only work with port 80 and 443. If you need custom port, you'll need to use Azure Virtual Machine to host your application

Comment: So how do I specify them? In the Flask main.py file or in the Azure Cloud Shell?

Comment: I think you just need to switch the  WEBSITES_PORT=8000 to  WEBSITES_PORT=80

Comment: it is still crashing but I just found this in my logs:

`2020-04-24T17:29:36.035250130Z 2020-04-24 17:29:36.035021: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-04-24T17:29:36.035859545Z 2020-04-24 17:29:36.035370: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:318] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)`

This might cause problems as well...

Comment: update to my last comment: when I run the app locally (where everything works) I get the same error. However, it tells me that I can ignore it when I don't want to use a GPU (which I don't). So is there a way to specifically tell Azure not to use a GPU?

Comment: So, the application works now but only with less resources. the models I wanted to deploy seem to be to big to handle without access to better service plans etc.

Comment: You can try deploy them on ACI (Azure Container Instances)